# Flutter app does not show the image - Unable to load asset

Tags: image, flutter, assets

I'm following a tutorial in flutter where I had to add an image file to the app, I did it like the example but when I run the app nothing shows.

I tried to change and copy the path but the same result every time.
I change the `pubspec.file` as explained.

This is part of the code:

```
          Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/images/download.jpg'),
                Text('Food Paradise')
              ],
```

This is from the pubspec:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
assets:
    - assets/images/download.jpg
```

This is from the RUN log:

```
  I/flutter (19491): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE 
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (19491): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image 
codec:
I/flutter (19491): Unable to load asset: assets/images/download.jpg
I/flutter (19491): 
I/flutter (19491): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (19491): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load 
(package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (19491): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (19491): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:429:44)
I/flutter (19491): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (19491): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:414:14)
I/flutter (19491): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>. 
<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:267:86)
I/flutter (19491): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:143:20)
I/flutter (19491): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:267:63)
I/flutter (19491): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (19491): 
I/flutter (19491): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: 
"assets/images/download.jpg")
I/flutter (19491): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: 
PlatformAssetBundle#49af1(), name:
I/flutter (19491): "assets/images/download.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

The app is running but no image shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly it looks like the `pubspec.yaml` file content is not properly indented.

It should be something like

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/jpgs/test.jpg
```

Furthermore, check if your file is at the correct path, which is relative to `pubspec.yaml`.
Lastly, run `flutter packages get` to update the new file. then run `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

Answer (score 2):

if you think you typed all the code correctly then just Re-Run the Code rather than Hot Reload or Hot Restart. It worked for me.

Comment: Right, may be the author should check the reload limitations of flutter as well, because he wanted to use the hot-reload. Keep in mind that only the build path is evaluated in hot-reload.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you must include the directories when using the asset.
Image.asset("assets/images/apersonreading.jpg"),

Answer (score 0):

The Similar problem is occuring in my code but what I did is created an another folder for Images separated from the assets folder and move all of my Image and then Run this in my pubspec.yaml file

*flutter:
uses-material-design: true

assets:
- images/waiting.png*

and in part of my code I use this :

*Image.asset('images/waiting.png')*